# Nested brackets/chars '(' and ')' in grammar/ANTLRWorks warning: Decision can match input such as ... using multiple alternatives

Tags: nested, char, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

The grammar below parses `( left part = right part # comment )`, `# comment` is optional.

Two questions:

1. Sometimes warning (ANTLRWorks 1.4.2):
   **Decision can match input such as "{Int, Word}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2** (referencing `id2`)
   But only sometimes!
2. The next extension should be that the comment (`id2`) can contain chars '(' and ')'.

The grammar:

```
grammar NestedBrackets1a1;

//==========================================================
// Lexer Rules
//==========================================================

Int
  :  Digit+
  ;

fragment Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;

Special
  : ( TCUnderscore | TCQuote )
  ;
TCListStart   : '(' ; 
TCListEnd     : ')' ;   
fragment TCUnderscore  : '_' ;
fragment TCQuote       : '"' ;

// A word must start with a letter
Word
  :  ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Special ) ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Special | Digit )*
  ;

Space
  :  ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;

//==========================================================
// Parser Rules
//==========================================================

assignment
  :  TCListStart id1 '=' id1 ( comment )? TCListEnd
  ;

id1
  :  Word+
  ;

comment
  : '#' ( id2 )*
  ;

id2
  :  ( Word | Int )+
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***ANTLRStarter wrote:***
>
> Sometimes warning (ANTLRWorks 1.4.2): Decision can match input such as "{Int, Word}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 (referencing id2)
>   But only sometimes!

No, the grammar you posted will *always* produce this warning. Perhaps you don't always notice it (your IDE-plugin or ANTLRWorks might show it in a tab you don't have opened), but the warning is there. Convince yourself by creating a lexer/parser from the command line:

```
java -cp antlr-3.4-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool NestedBrackets1a1.g
```

will produce:

```
warning(200): NestedBrackets1a1.g:49:19:
Decision can match input such as "{Int, Word}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

This is because you have a `*` after `( id2 )` inside your `comment` rule, and `id2` also is a repetition of tokens: `( Word | Int )+`. Let's say your input is `"# foo bar"` (a `#` followed by two `Word` tokens). ANTLR can now parse the input in more than 1 way: the 2 tokens `"foo"` and `"bar"` could be matched by `( id2 )*`, where `id2` matches a single `Word` token at a time, but `"foo"` and `"bar"` could also be matches in one go of the  `id2` rule.

Look at the merged rules:

```java
comment
  :  '#' ( ( Word | Int )+ )*
  ;
```

See how you're repeating a repetition: `( ( ... )+ )*`? This is usually a problem, as it is in your case.

Resolve this problem by either replacing the `*` with a `?`:

```java
comment
  :  '#' ( id2 )?
  ;

id2
  :  ( Word | Int )+
  ;
```

or by removing the `+`:

```java
comment
  :  '#' ( id2 )*
  ;

id2
  :  ( Word | Int )
  ;
```

> ***ANTLRStarter wrote:***
>
> The next extension should be that the comment (id2) can contain chars '(' and ')'.

That is asking for trouble since a comment is followed by a `TCListEnd`, which is a `)`. I don't recommend letting a comment match `)`.

### EDIT

Note that comments are usually stripped from the source file while tokenizing the input source. That way you don't need to account for them in your parser rules. You can do that by "skipping" these tokens in a lexer rule:

```java
Comment
  :  '#' ~('\r' | '\n')* {skip();}
  ;
```

Comment: Bart, many thanks again. In the real grammar, the comment is a line comment, that means there must be a '\n' at the end. I added that and now I haven't any problems with the brackets '(' and ')'. But is there any common approach to solve that problem without the '\n'?

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, ah okay, the `\n` at the end makes it different. Usually a comment should end with a certain char (or more). Like `\n` for single line, or `*/` for multi-line. How you described it, a comment didn't end with anything special and could contain a char that was already used in some other way (the `TCListEnd`, in your case). Also see my EDIT.

Comment: Bart, new findings, see my comment in your answer!

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, since you haven't enough rep-points, your edit to my answer was pending and needed 2 votes (from users with enough rep) for approval. It seems to have been rejected since I see no changes to my answer. Note that if you have further questions, you either edit your original question, or you post a new question here on SO. You shouldn't post follow-up questions inside answers. Be careful with multiple edits of your own question: by doing so, (parts of) answers may become invalid since you changed the question. However, I think I answered your original question, ...

Comment: and the best you can do is create a new question with your current problem(s). Also consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem. But if your current problem is not resolved by my answer, feel free to make a small edit to your own question, or ask for clarification in a comment (not by editing my answer!). Good luck!